# Select sub-set of list based on random values

Tags: c#, linq

What I want to do is something like:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var list1Data = ...; //100 elements
var list2Data = list1Data.Where(_ => rnd.NextDouble() > 0.1);
```

In other words about 90% of list items should be selected, about 10% are not... it's simulating very simply a faulty piece of equipment.

But I get 100% of items returned instead. How can I remedy this?

**UPDATE:**
*when I look in the debugger it shows list2.Count is the same as list1.Count BUT when I expand the results view, it shows fewer elements... i.e. it's doing as it should but the debugger is showing confusing information.*

[image]

In this example expanding `Results View` shows around 90 elements from run to run, but `Count` shows 100.

Is this a bug in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator or my misunderstanding?

Comment: _"I think rnd.NextDouble() is only getting called once..."_ - please read [ask] and explain your problem very explicitly, including a [mcve]. Guessing isn't going to get you very far here. Obviously you observed something that makes you think so, but if you don't mention your observations but just your thoughts, we can't say anything useful.

Comment: No, your edit does not help. Again, read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. This code is extremely unlikely to return the entire `list1` contents in `list2`. Again, provide a [mcve]. You're probably not using `rnd`, but `new Random()` in the `Where()` statement or whatever.

Comment: What's `rnd` then? Don't you *recreate* `Random` instance and thus have a badly skewed instance?

Comment: Using a `new Random()` initialized outside the list and iterating produces "correct" results, it seems.

Comment: "extremely unlikely"... now who's guessing. I'll throw an example together but I thought someone might be able to answer off the top of their head

Comment: as Scott said, works for me. Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4KTOW

Comment: Works for me too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WtBTBO

Comment: @Nico thanks your exaple basically would be my MCVE so now I'm confused more ;)

Comment: And you are DEFINITELY using `list2` subsequently, and not accidentally using `list1`?

Comment: Anyway I'm saying it's "extremely unlikely" because _if_ the actual problematic code were that in your question, _and_ you have an extremely small list, _and_ `rnd.NextDouble()` would return a value of <= 0.1 on every call for each of the items in that list, upon every run (because Random is seeded with the current time) only _then_ you would consistently see the behavior you're describing - and that's simply nigh impossible.

Comment: @Mr.Boy where `list1` comes from? Is it from database?

Comment: Bah... so when I look in the debugger it shows `list2.Count` is the same as `list1.Count` _BUT_ when I expand the results view, it shows fewer elements... i.e. it's doing as it should but the debugger is showing confusing information. Is this a bug in `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator` or my misunderstanding?

Comment: Not really sure how to reword my question... or post my own answer... or just delete it?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, the result is a query; opening it executes the query.  Since the query involves a random element, depending on what is in List1, the result can be different each time

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you mean. WhereListIterator doesn't have a Count property. Are you looking at source.Count?

Comment: @CodeCaster added. I think the whole nature of my question has changed, if you can think of a better title please feel free to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at `WhereListIterator.`**`source`**`.Count`.

Given the `source` field holds a reference to the `List<T>` it's going to iterate over, it is showing you the **count of the source collection**, not the count of the filtered collection.

There is no property or field that indicates the count of the latter, because that is only known after iterating over the entire source collection, and that's deferred until you actually do that, for example using `foreach()`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I suppose often we append `.ToList()` or similar. I've been caught out by the debugger changing program behaviour before when inspecting data structures linked to deferred results.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the risks when using the debugger to stuff that's supposed to be executed in a deferred manner. `ToList()` generally is a good approach.